# How do I use a CSV to supply data for a vbar using Bokehplotting?

Tags: python, csv, bokeh

I am trying to use Bokeh glyphs with data from a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
df= pd.read_csv('./lecturespace/2013data.csv',names = ['Birth','Death','Young','Old'])
print(df)
```

Birth   Death  Young  Old

436500 266257 37014 6023

I am new to dealing with bokeh using csv files. I tried to configure the data myself, but strange graphs have been drawn for several hours. Thank you for reading. I really want to how to deal this. Please help me..

i really want to create like these pictures.
[gridplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7lQg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this is your DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Word':["Birth", "Death", "Young", "Old"],
    'Amount': [436500, 266257, 37014, 6023],
    'color': ['red', 'blue']*2
})
```

then you want to split the data from the DataFrame into two sources, to show it in two figures you want to display in a `row` layout.

```
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

p1 = figure(width=400, height=400, y_range=list(df.Word.iloc[:2]))
p1.hbar(y="Word", left=0, right='Amount', color='color', height=0.75, source=df.iloc[:2])

p2 = figure(width=400, height=400, y_range=list(df.Word.iloc[2:]))
p2.hbar(y="Word", left=0, right='Amount', color='color', height=0.75, source=df.iloc[2:])

show(row(p1,p2))
```

It is important to define the `y_range` to activate the categorical axes.See also [this example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/bars/colors.html) from the offical gallary.